# How to add slash after every string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, text, str-replace

How i can add a slash or ; after every string. Here i have an Example:

This is what i have

```
"SKU" "TITLE" "LINK" "LINK2" "PRICE" "World of Warcraft"
```

But i will have like that

```
"SKU";"TITLE";"LINK";"LINK2";"PRICE";"World of Warcraft"
```

How i can made this? I work with affiliate and this Partner dont give `CSV`. Its only an `TXT` file.
So, how i can add slash into every "string"?
i already tried to add `;` after every 2nd `"`. But it dont work with my code...
also tried with `str_replace()`

```
str_replace(" ", ";", $item);
```

Comment: my string is not  $string="SKU TITLE LINK LINK2 PRICE"; 
the string ist like that  $string=' "SKU" "TITLE" "LINK" "LINK2" "PRICE" ';

If i make like yours @felixsturm than i have SKU TITLE LINK LINK2 PRICE; and not SKU;TITLE;LINK;LINK2;PRICE

Comment: https://3v4l.org/hJt6h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$str = '"61926182767182" "DAS GEILE GAME" "HTTP://google.com/123129182691239" "HTTP://google.com/123129182691239" "32.59"';
$str = preg_replace("/(\"[^\"]+\")\s/", "$1;", $str);

print_r($str);  // '"61926182767182";"DAS GEILE GAME";"HTTP://google.com/123129182691239";"HTTP://google.com/123129182691239";"32.59"'
```

(this approach can be easily extended if there would be tabs instead of spaces in the input string OR if there may be multiple spaces between words. It's more flexible)

Comment: this approach can be easily extended if there would be tabs instead of spaces in the input string OR if there may be multiple spaces between words. It's more flexible

Comment: @Mohammad no its not working. Problem is that a Title have Like that "World of Warcraft"... there also spaces that gets the ; than

Comment: @Scholli, can you show  the input string with that part `"World of Warcraft"` ? I'll adjust my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can split string by `" "` delimiter using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and join result array with `";"` string using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$str = implode('";"', explode('" "', $str))
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/5in4X)